# Export MYSQL phpadmin to Excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

I am a little new to MYSQL and PHP so any help is much appreciated. I have a database right now that is storing ten values, a name and 9 scores. I also have an excel spreadsheet that has the names and empty slots for those 9 scores. I have a bunch of formulas that use those 9 scores to calculate other scores. Is it possible to read those 9 scores for each individual name from my database then place them into that specific slot of the spread sheet based on there name? I do not want to write to a new spread sheet but rather input these scores into that spreadsheet that is being used. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In PhpMyAdmin **select your database**, then **export** -> **CSV** or **CSV for MS Excel**

Take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes I understand how to export it to a new file. I am wondering if I can export it to a specific spreadsheet I have already made and if I can make this automated

Comment: With PhpMyAdmin it's not possible. I think you should before export it manually and then import it wherever you want!

Comment: Do you know if this is possible with PHP or would I just be wasting my time?